# Property 'prototype' does not exist

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am trying to use `jest` and mock `ioredis` in typescript.

The issue is that I am getting an error from `typescript` that:

```
tests/__mocks__/ioredis.ts(5,9): error TS2339: Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'Redis''
```

The code does work, but I would like to solve this error.
Here is my mock:

```
// tests/__mocks__/ioredis.ts
import { Redis } from 'ioredis';

const IORedis: Redis = jest.genMockFromModule<Redis>('ioredis');

IORedis.prototype.hgetall = jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (key: string) => {
    // Some mock implementation
});

module.exports = IORedis;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a no perfect solution.

First define a intereface with prototype property:

```
interface IPrototype { prototype: any; }
```

The use *IORedis* like this to have access to prototype and ohter Redis methods.

```
(IORedis as IPrototype & Redis).prototype ...
```

**Another option** might be to declare your const like this:

```
interface IPrototype { prototype: any; }
type MyRedis = Redis & IPrototype;
const IORedis: MyRedis = jest.genMockFromModule<MyRedis>('ioredis');
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If the type you need to extend is generic, you can use type variables when creating the union type.

```
interface IPrototype { prototype: any; }
type ExtendedType<A, B> = IPrototype & BasicType<A, B>;
```

Then you can cast using

```
(myvar as ExtendedType<any, any>).prototype
```